# How do you provide an API Gateway integration authorisation to call a Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

When setting up an API to call an AWS Lambda function from the AWS API Gateway **UI Console**, you get asked whether you give API Gateway permission to call the Lambda function .

What is the equivalent when doing it via the **AWS CLI**?

I have set up two resources and two methods- one through the console and one through the command line.

When I call the one set up through the console, it works fine.

But when I call the one set up through the CLI, I get a response

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

and if i test it through the API Gateway Test feature, I see

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add permission to Lambda for the principal which is `apigateway.amazonaws.com` in your case.

E.g.

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name LambdaFunctionOverHttps \
--statement-id apigateway-prod-2 --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:$API/prod/POST/DynamoDBManager"
```

Here is the [add-permission API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html).